# javascript error SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Trying to make an array of strings inside array of objects and getting an error saying SyntaxError: missing : after property id for the code below in javascript

```
let movies = [
  {
  movie title: 'Avengers: Age of Ultron',
  release year: '2015',
  rating:'7.3',
  "genres"=[0:"Action",1:"Adventure",2:"Sci-Fi"]
},
{
  movie title: 'The Dark Knight',
  release year:'2008',
  rating:'9.0',
  genres:["Action","Crime","Drama"]
},
{
  movie title: 'Forrest Gump',
  release year:'1994',
  rating:'8.8',
  genres:["Drama","Romance"]
},
{
  movie title: 'Inception',
  release year:'2010',
  rating:'8.8',
  genres:["Action","Adventure","Sci-Fi"]
},
{
  movie title: 'The Matrix',
  release year:'1999',
  rating:'8.7',
  genres:["Action","Sci-Fi"]
},
{
  movie title: 'Border',
  release year:'1997',
  rating:'7.9',
  genres:["Action","Drama","History"]
}
  ];
```

Comment: error coming up on line 6

Comment: There is an equals sign after “genres”. Plus you probably shouldn’t be assigning arrays with keys.

Comment: `"genres"=[0:"Action",1:"Adventure",2:"Sci-Fi"]`

Comment: Apart from what you have already been told, object keys containing a space should be surrounded by quotes (e.g. `{ 'movie title': 'Avengers: Age of Ultron' }` instead of `{ movie title: 'Avengers: Age of Ultron' }`). Finally, object keys containing space can be accessed only with the bracket notation (`obj['key containing space']`). My suggestion is *not* to use keys like those and use camel case (`movieTitle`) or keys with underscores (`movie_title`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code.

1. If JSON object key contains ' ', you should write ".
2. You don't need to write an index to your JSON object value.

Here's the updated code.

```
let movies = [
    {
    "movie title": 'Avengers: Age of Ultron',
    "release year": '2015',
    rating:'7.3',
    genres:["Action", "Adventure", "Sci-Fi"]
  },
  {
    "movie title": 'The Dark Knight',
    "release year":'2008',
    rating:'9.0',
    genres:["Action","Crime","Drama"]
  },
  {
    "movie title": 'Forrest Gump',
    "release year":'1994',
    rating:'8.8',
    genres:["Drama","Romance"]
  },
  {
    "movie title": 'Inception',
    "release year":'2010',
    rating:'8.8',
    genres:["Action","Adventure","Sci-Fi"]
  },
  {
    "movie title": 'The Matrix',
    "release year":'1999',
    rating:'8.7',
    genres:["Action","Sci-Fi"]
  },
  {
    "movie title": 'Border',
    "release year":'1997',
    rating:'7.9',
    genres:["Action","Drama","History"]
  }
    ];
```